# Can traditional and simplified counterparts have different pronunciations?

Tags: characters, pronunciation, traditional-vs-simplified

Can traditional and simplified counterparts have different pronunciations? For example, 兄 [xiōng] (elder) brother becomes 儿 [ér], right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional character for 儿 is 兒. They are pronounced the same [ér].